# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Google App Engine App

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a website running on my own domain, and it has a form that has an action pointing to my google appspot domain. The app spot app is running a very simple python script which is below:

```
import cgi,webapp2


class ProblemRedirect(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        print(cgi.escape(self.request.get('problem_text')))
        print(cgi.escape(self.request.get('student_name')))
        print(cgi.escape(self.request.get('student_email')))



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', ProblemRedirect),
], debug=True)
```

Here's the HTML for my form:

```
<div id="mainForm">
            <form id="problem_form" class="problem_form" action="http://www.summit-tech-help.appspot.com" method="post">
                <textarea id="problemText" placeholder="Explain your problem in detail. Click the black bar on top, for rules!" form="problem_form" rows="15" cols="45" name="problem_text" autofocus required></textarea></br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email..." name="student_email" required/></br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name..." name="student_name" required/></br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit!" required/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

This form is on another web server, but is processed by the appspot script. However, whenever I submit my form, I get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.summit-tech-help.appspot.com/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Also, I deployed the app from Google App Engine Launcher on OSX. When I click "run" on the Launcher, it runs on localhost:8080, so will I be able to see the "print" when it works? Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your handler:

```
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

replacing the star characer (which accepts every host) with the origin you want to accept. See [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/responseclass)